# I'm Confused About Size, Combinatorial Classes and Counting Sequences

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

My Teacher tried to explain these concepts like so:

[image]

**My Problem**

I'm quite confused by the definition given. How can "the size" which is a function mapped from our countable set A to all the non-negative integers, be a non-negative integer? Aren't numbers and functions two distinct mathematical objects? I'm also pretty confused by what is meant by "If for every $n$ there are finitely many elements of A of size n then we call A a combinatorial class" could someone explain to me what is combinatorial class?

Comment: "Size" is being used here as an arbitrary attribute of each element of A. The function is like an inquiry, "tell me the size of"  this element of A.

Comment: @Joffan so the output of the function (which will be a non negative integer) is what the size is?

Comment: exactly, but then you can use function-type analysis on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition uses the word *size* for two different things. First, each element of $\mathcal{A}$ has an attribute *size* that is a non-negative integer. For instance, if $\mathcal{A}=\Bbb Z^+$, we might define the size of of $n\in\mathcal{A}$ to be the number of distinct prime factors of $n$. In that case the sizes of $2,3,4$, and $5$ would all be $1$, but the size of $6$ would be $2$, and the size of $1$ would be $0$. This attribute gives us a size function from $\mathcal{A}$ to the set of non-negative integers, a function that assigns to each $a\in\mathcal{A}$ its size. The definition that you’ve been given calls this size function simply the *size* rather than the *size function*. As a (slightly confusing) result, the word *size* is used both for the function and for its values. You’re absolutely right in thinking that these are different things; the author of that definition has simply chosen to use the same word for both.

If we have a countable family $\mathcal{A}$ equipped with a size function that assigns to each $a\in\mathcal{A}$ a non-negative integer $|a|$, called the size of $a$, we can ask how many elements of $\mathcal{A}$ have size $0$, how many have size $1$, and so on. If $n$ is a non-negative integer, let $\mathcal{A}_n=\{a\in\mathcal{A}:|a|=n\}$ be the set of $a\in\mathcal{A}$ of size $n$. If all of the sets $\mathcal{A}_n$ are finite, we call $\mathcal{A}$ a *combinatorial class*.

The family $\mathcal{A}$ in my example is **not** a combinatorial class: $\mathcal{A}_0=\{1\}$ is finite, because $1$ is the only positive integer with $0$ distinct prime factors, but $\mathcal{A}_1$ is infinite: it includes all primes, and positive powers of primes.

If $\mathcal{A}$ **is** a combinatorial class, for each non-negative integer $n$ we let $a_n$ be the number of elements of size $n$, i.e., the number of elements of the set $\mathcal{A}_n$: since we’re dealing with a combinatorial class, each $a_n$ is a non-negative integer. It can be $0$: there might not be any elements of $\mathcal{A}$ of size $3$, say, in which case $a_3=0$. Finally, the sequence $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle=\langle a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots\rangle$ is called the *counting sequence* of the combinatorial class $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: And $A$ must be a combinatorial class for it to have a counting sequence? Why couldn't we just put $\infty$ for $a_1$ in your original example. Also, thanks for your great answer.

Comment: @Dunka: Yes, we talk about the counting sequence only when we have a combinatorial class. One of the main tools for studying these things is the *generating function*, which uses the $a_n$ as coefficients in a power series, and for that we definitely need them to be finite. If all we wanted to do was describe the sizes of the sets $\mathcal{A}_n$, we could do something similar to what you suggest, but then we’d be dealing with what turns out to be a rather different kind of object, one that needs rather different tools. \\ You’re very welcome.

Comment: Good intro. (+1)

Comment: @Marko: Thanks!